# Warning for limited Access

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is regarding ASP.NET MVC.
Let's say I have a web site that is accessed publicly name as "www.welcomeeveryone.com". There is also a web site name as "www.companyemployeeonly.com" that is allowed only for certain range of IP address. Employees have to go to "www.welcomeeveryone.com" first in order to have a link for "www.companyemployeeonly.com".
Here is my question. How do I detect the user is in the allowed IP or not and give them a warning like popup or some kind of notification. When they are not in the certain IP address, then they have to use VPN connection.

Comment: Why not use the built-in IP address restrictions in IIS7? Or do you not have that version of IIS?

Comment: I am using IIS7 with Windows Server 2008, but I want to provide a warning to users to let them know they need to be in company or VPN connection. It is because they are coming from public web site link. But I will keep that in mind as an option since I was not think about it. Thanks.

Comment: Then why not create your own custom 403 page and display that when the user hits it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the remote IP using

```
Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"]
```

Then converting to [IpAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress(v=VS.100).aspx) and then you can use this functions to convert it to long and make the compare

```
public long addrToNum(IPAddress Address)
{
    byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(Address.Address);

    if (b.Length == 8)
        return (long)(((long)16777216 * b[0]) + ((long)(65536 * b[1])) + ((long)(256 * b[2])) + b[3]);
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Be ware that the Remore_Host is not valid if he is behind proxy, and you need to discover that, and also can be hacked.

Comment: What do you mean by "can be hacked"? Who might be hacked?

Comment: @hoorayo This is a parameter that can be send by the user with different ip than the real one. Its not 100% accurate.